# when you extend a private class. are the public and protected members of class become private

Tags: java

when you extend a private class. Are the public and protected members of class become private. if not any explanation.

Comment: can you create upper level class as private class?? :D

Comment: No, we cannot create.but for nested class we can.
My question is what is the behavior of members of private class if it is inherited.

Answer (score 1):

if you extend a nested private class, it wont change public/protected modifiers of the members. Here is an example :

```
public class Clazz {

    private static class NestedClazz {
        public int value = 123;
    }

    public static class NestedClazzExt extends NestedClazz {
    }
}
```

you can now access the inherited member: `value` from outside

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    NestedClazzExt nestedClazz = new Clazz.NestedClazzExt();
    System.out.println(nestedClazz.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create private class in side a class . We call it as Nested classe. Means a class inside a class. The Concept itself is saying that you can create private class in side another class. The private class will act like as data member to the outer class. 
So, You can't extend the private class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Based on your query I tried to prepare a simple class.


public class pvtClass {

    private class As {
        public String abc = "private attribute";

        public void print(){
            System.out.println("privateClass");
        }
    }

    class Ab extends As{
        public String ab = "extended attribute";

        public void printAb(){
            System.out.println("extended class");
            print();
            System.out.println(abc);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String as[]){
        Ab ab1 = (new pvtClass()).new Ab();
        As as1 = (new pvtClass()).new As();

        ab1.printAb();
        as1.print();
        System.out.println(as1.abc);
    }
}

If you have a look at this class, I have a private class named "As" which has public attribute and public methods. I have another class named "Ab" which extends "As". I have written a main method to invoke the private attribute and methods.
```

below is the output for the code snippet:

extended class
privateClass
private attribute
privateClass
private attribute

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the access of the members of a class and the access to the type itself.

```
public class C {
    private class InnerP1 {
        public void m() {
            System.out.println("InnerP1.m()");
        }
    }

    private class InnerP2 extends InnerP1 {
        public void p() {
            this.m();
            System.out.println("InnerP2.p()");
        }
    }

    public InnerP1 strange() {
        return new InnerP2();
    }
}
```

In this example, the interface `I` is visible from outside class `C`. The classes `InnerP1` and `InnerP2` are not visible from outside `C`. Jave itself makes not restrictions to the visibility of types you use in your public interface. The method `strange()` of class `C` returns a result of class `InnerP1`. Since outside of `C` we do not know anything about the class `InnerP1` other than it is subtype of `Object`, the only thing we can do is use the result of `strange()` as an `Object`.

```
public class D {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C();
        Object o = c.strange();
        if(o.equals(c.strange())) {
            System.out.println("Strange things are going on here!");
        }
    }
}
```

As @KnusperPudding pointed out already, the visiblity of public members is not changed, we might just not have enough knowledge of the type itself to access them.

Answer (score 0):

Access to members cannot be restricted by sub-classing.  When you mark a class as private then access via the class name is restricted i.e. to the same `.java` file, however once you have an instance of this class it can be accessed at least as easily as the super class.